# How to migrate core profile fields into the new profile fields in D7?

Tags: 7, migrations, users

**Premises:**

I´m trying to upgrade a big D6 site to D7.

I have the content profile module installed.

I have a few core profile fields that I need to keep.

The "profile" node that was created by the content profile module, has no fields in it. I just used in order to manage in a better way the theming and presentation of profiles.

I´ve installed Profile2 module. I´ve installed the profile page submodule that comes bundled with it.

**My 2 problems:**

**1.** I would like to export or convert all those core profile fields into the new entity fields in D7. **How may I do that?**

**2.** In the meanwhile (in case number 1 is just not possible at all), I´ve tried theming the ***profile2.tpl.php*** file, trying to print into it my old core profile fields.

I´ve [followed the instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1488468) to print those core profile fields, so I´ve harcoded this `print check_plain($account->profile_nombre);` into the template, but it doesn´t print the name of the user that´s inserted into the *nombre* field (core profile field). So, how may I theme the profile page?

I´ve watched [this video tutorial](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-profile-2-module) also, about the profile2 module, but I´m still absolutely clueless on how to manage profiles in D7 when you already have a couple thousand users with core profile fields in it.

***Please note that I´ve tried using the "migrate" module, and the "drupal 2 drupal" migration module, with no luck.***

Thanks for your help and insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A good solution might be to use Feeds module (to import to fields) and Views Data Export Module (to export fields to the spreadsheet). The procedure would be:
>
> Setup a view that lists all of your users and displays all of the
>   fields you want to migrate. Then add news display (data export) and
>   choose CSV format.
>
> Use feeds to import the data to D7. Just map each exported field to a
>   new field.
>
> This might seem complicated at first, but it's really simple and
>   should work.

Thanks for your reply, [take2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637548/take2). Thought it would be good to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this module (more of a drush extension) to convert the content profile fields to core profile fields or profile 2 fields (recommended) once your site is a D7 site: [CP2P2](https://drupal.org/project/cp2p2)